# Presentation error in ShareCode.io.code output is correct but not well-formed with white spaces

Tags: c++

Link of question:
http://sharecode.io/section/utap/problem/1005
The error says code output is correct but not well-formed with white spaces.
I've tried using a blank space between columns of output and it did not work.
I don't know how to well-form the output using white spaces.
how can I fix this error?!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void swap(string& a,string& b)
{
     string temp;
     temp=a;
     a=b;
     b=temp;
}


void apply_gravity(vector<string>& net,int rows , int columns)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            if (net[i][j] == 'a') 
            {
                for (int k = rows - 1; k > i; k--)
                {
                   if (net[k][j] == '.')
                    {
                        for (int b = k - 1; b >= i;b--)
                        {
                            if (net[b][j] == '#')
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                swap(net[i][j], net[k][j]);
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}





int main()
{

    int rows;
    int columns;
    cin >> rows >> columns;
    vector<string> net(rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {

        cin >> net[i];
    }
    columns = net[0].length();
    apply_gravity(net, rows, columns);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << net[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide your input and your desired output. Your problem is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the lines

```
cout << endl;
```

and

```
cout << net[i];
```

Your output begins with a newline. The example output does not.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but got the error "wrong answer" !